# strange performance issue

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

I have a production site and a test site hosted on the same server (dev.mysite.com and www.mysite.com)
While the performance of product, category and cms pages are equivalent, there is a 1 to 4 (sometimes 1 to 15) ratio between both sites with checkout/cart and checkout/onepage, test site being the fastest.

What is strange is that the code and database are identical (database copied through mysqldump and import).

What i already checked :

- htaccess : identical
- apache vhost settings : identical
- magento profiler : doesn't point to a clear suspect
- server activity : performance inconsistency persists even if no visit recorded on the production site
- admin operations : performance inconsistency persists when no operations on the backend

I'm running out of idea, what would you check next ?

Comment: Have you checked your cronjobs? Maybe you have more active modules on your production site.

Comment: How do you measure the performance (difference)?

Comment: I guess he's using a browser inspector, this way he has access to loading time of each element.
Have you tried restarting apache/mysql on the server then test performance afterwards?

Comment: browser inspector allow me to compare both sites, but i first noticed the performance issue on production site because i track loading times on google analytics.

Comment: Maybe it's caching related? The cache might be disabled on the dev-system? But that should also make a difference on the other pages as well.

Comment: Cache settings are identical...
Still didn't find what maybe the difference between both sites that might explain the performance issue...